# ForeColor en columna de Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo en el page load de mi página una condición para deshabilitar un LinkButton y cambiar el color de la letra. El atributo Enabled funciona pero ForeColor no, aquí esta mi código:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    LlenarGridview(GridView1_Persona, Datos);
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1_Persona.Rows)
    {
         if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              if (row.Cells[2].Text == "Aprobado")
              {
                   row.Cells[3].Enabled = false;
                   row.Cells[3].ForeColor=Color.Gray;
              }else
              {
                   row.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.Green;
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya lo intenté, Style no tiene método ForeColor pero ControlStyle sí y no genera error pero igual  no funciona.

Comment: En la línea `row.Cells[3].ForeColor.Equals(Color.Gray);` no asigna el `ForeColor` solo compara si es igual a `Color.Gray` como está el código en su linea dentro del else , debería funcionar.

Comment: Joel arriba estaba igual que en el else pero igual no funciona lo cambié haciendo intentos y olvidé cambiarlo.

Comment: prueba con la propiedad Style de cells , ej row.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor=Color.Gray;

Comment: @WFgo eso es para Windows Form , esto es `GridView` en `ASP`  , Katty creo que la linea `row.Cells[3].ForeColor=Color.Gray;`  es correcta, habrá algo por ahí que este causando esto que en su código no se aprecia

Comment: Ya intenté poner Style y genera error al parecer no tiene método ForeColor, puse ControlStyle que no generó error pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: Una pregunta debido a que es un linkbutton el genera un color azul y un subrayado por defecto. ¿Hay algún atributo como el de css text-decoration:none para quitar este estilo por defecto?

Comment: Por que no modificas directamente el LinkButton en lugar de la celda?

Comment: Porque no lo he podido llamar no me trae el ID.

Comment: esto no lo deberías hacer en RowDataBound y no en el pageload.... nunca lo he hecho en el pageload, por eso la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1_Persona.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Text != "Aprobado")
        {
                 LinkButton lbtn = row.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
                 lbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```